# Is it possible to use messageDefinitionSends for multiple business units with one app?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, email

I have previously created and have been using one app to perform triggered sends with [messageDefinitionSends](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/messaging/messageDefinitionSends.html). I now have the additional requirement of creating more sends that are defined under another business unit(we will call it busUnt2).

When I make the post to any trigger in  busUnt2 `https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:TEST_EXTERNAL_TRIGGER_ID/send?access_token=******r5afcz`

I get a `404` error

```
{
   "message": "Not Found",
   "errorcode": 0,
   "documentation": "https://code.docs.exacttarget.com/rest/errors/404"
}
```

I created a new app linked to busUnt2 to test and the trigger and it sends fine.

How can I configure my original app to send triggers built in any business unit?

Comment: I believe when creating an APP in appcenter, the access token can only be used for that BU that it was created for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A second set of App Keys would need to be generated in App Center.  When creating the app, at the authentication step there is an option to select the business  unit they will be associated with.

Comment: This is cumbersome but correct. I did end up using 2 app keys... which also means 2 calls for security tokens and some logic and settings to know which key is for which business unit and for which triggered send.